# Windows 7 in Boot Camp can't read other FAT32 partitions

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, boot-camp, gpt

On my Mid-2009 MacBook Pro, I have OSX 10.6.8 installed, Windows 7 (through Boot Camp), and 2 FAT32 partitions. The extra two partitions are not visible to Windows 7, but they are visible on the OSX side.

Below is the output of `diskpart`, trying to show the volumes:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          698 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 2    Online          119 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C   BOOTCAMP     NTFS   Partition    111 GB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     E   MacMan 1     HFS    Partition    111 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3     G                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 4     F   Lexar        FAT32  Removable    119 GB  Healthy

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            200 MB    512 B
  Partition 2    Primary            111 GB   200 MB
  Partition 3    Primary            111 GB   111 GB
  Partition 4    Primary            619 MB   223 GB
```

This is my Disk Management screen, trying to show the extra volumes:

[image: <>]

First partition is the EFI System Partition, C: is Boot Camp (Windows 7), E: is my Mac drive (can't edit files on there), the 620MB partition is the OSX Recovery Partition, and it sees the last half of the disk as Unallocated, but there are two FAT32 partitions in there.

What can I do to view these two FAT32 partitions that were created on the OSX side?

Comment: last time I checked windows only likes one primary partition per volume

Comment: You can have up to 4 primary partitions on an mbr formatted disk, since the dos days. That's not the issue here. As well, volumes do not contain partitions.

Comment: yeah, that's possible, but windows would only see one of them last time I checked.

Comment: No... It will see all primary partitions that it can understand a file system for. If it has more than 4 partitions, it automatically creates an extended partition, and logical partitions inside that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are your other FAT partitions are not included in the hybrid MBR, which is a topic you ***MUST*** understand if you're to do anything remotely unusual on a dual-boot of OS X and Windows 7. See this page of mine for more information:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html

In brief, a hybrid MBR takes up to three GPT partitions and "mirrors" them in the MBR for Windows to see. No more than three partitions can be so mirrored, but on a typical installation, one or two of those partitions will be OS X partitions, leaving any extras on the GPT side only. To correct the problem, you must use a more sophisticated tool for creating a hybrid MBR, such as `gdisk`.

Beware, though: Windows sometimes reacts strangely to partition table changes made by other OSes or tools. Thus, if you change your hybrid MBR, Windows may react strangely, up to and including not booting at all. It may help to ensure that the Windows partition retains its original position in the MBR -- that is, if the Windows `C:` partition is partition #4 in the MBR now, ensure that it's partition #4 in your new hybrid MBR, too, even if that means that partitions that come after `C:` in terms of disk space get numbers 2 and/or 3 in the new hybrid MBR.